# Besides reinstalling Eclipse 32 bit is there a way around using a -d32 flag on a JVM from a mac with os x 10.6.8?

Tags: eclipse, macos, jvm, 32bit-64bit, lejos-nxj

Essentially I am trying to use the lejos runtime along with lejos libraries for a project and so I get the error from my Eclipse nxt_project that I do not have the NXTCommException class. I did some research and apparently I can only run my project on a 32 bit JVM, but my Eclipse distribution is 64 bit and I really don't want to have to reinstall everything. The alternative was to change my bash profile to include my environment variables with the -d32 flag which I have read will not give me any results and in addition I"m not sure where to put the flag in my stated class path.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit Eclipse will only run on a 64-bit JVM, there's no way around that as far as I know. But installing another Eclipse is a pretty straightforward process; you can even point it to your existing workspace so you don't lose all your preferences and projects. As for installing extra plugins that you may have, you can use File > Import > From Existing Installation to install stuff from your old Eclipse into the new one.

Comment: When you start up Eclipse, it asks what workspace you want to use. Just select the workspace you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You may still need the -d32 flag even with 32 bit Eclipse.  The reason is that when you start a new process, your system will default (if the hardware supports it) to 64 bit even if you have 32 bit java preference set via java preferences (perplexing and counter intuitive but that is how it was when Lion was introduced.  May have changed).

Actually there is no need to reinstall. The -d32 is included now in any lejos scripts.  For starting a process from within Eclipse (to run on your mac and communicate with the NXT), you need to go to the RUN (eclipse menu) --> run configurations --> select your program --> arguments and put it in VM arguments.